# Python way to do crc32b

Tags: python, hash, crc

As i posted as title, there is a way to use the crc32b hash on python natively or through a library (i.e. chilkat)?

My intention is to "translate" a program from php to python, so output should be same as in php:

$hashedData= hash('crc32b',$data);

-> Edit: in a win32 system

Thanks to all ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[python-mhash](http://labix.org/python-mhash) supplies many hashing functions including crc32b.

Comment: Emm after trying so many things, including visual studio 2003 and so, i'm unable to compile that extension within a win32 system (which is my current & target system)

Comment: @Ragnagard, depending on your Python version, different approaches are recommended for building Python extensions on Windows. However in the past I've had good success on many different extensions and versions with mingw, http://www.mingw.org/ , or cygwin, http://www.cygwin.com/ -- see http://boodebr.org/main/python/build-windows-extensions for complete instructions.

Comment: @Alex Martelli, I have been there before posting/comment again. If you scroll down, you can see "Next challenge - mhash" comments, where they indicate that no solution has been made with free solutions to mhash compilation, unfortunatelly